# how to hide GET variable from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

i'v been stuck with this        `<a href="profile.php?u=<?php echo $uiname ?>"/>`
, i'm trying to hide the `$_GET` variable but no success. 
what i'm trying to achieve is something like `www.mywebsitename.com/profile/name` or `www.mywebsite.com/name` instead of

```
profile.php?u=name
```

is it possible to do so ?

Comment: You can find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448304/use-sos-url-format-for-get/4448518

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Your URL: `http://localhost/ifinal/profile/myname`

You can use like with htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ifinal/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) profile.php?u=$1
</IfModule>
```

If your site not underfolder, use just `RewriteBase /`

And use HTML

```
<a href="profile/<?php echo $uiname; ?>">
   <?php echo $uiname; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: do i just create .htaccess and paste this to it ? RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) /profile.php?u=$1
or i need to add something else to the .htaccess ?

Comment: @user2660611 updated codes. copy and paste exactly to root `.htaccess` and let me know about you getting any error or not. hope it work

Comment: it doesnt work , i'm using wamp server. i enabled the apache rewrite module and i uncommented LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so from the httpd.conf and nothing changes

Comment: What you get? What exactly your url? Root or subfolder?

Comment: i get the same as the old ones. i'v two profile.php,  one is at the main folder which includes some php files, and the actual profile.php is in subfolder called inc

Comment: Your site under subfolder? and if you enter `www.mywebsitename.com/profile/name` what you see?

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: u in C:\wamp\www\ifinal\func\user_profile_details.php on line 4
which i get the $_GET['u'];

Comment: It works for me. Updated codes. Try again pls. Watch out `RewriteBase`

Comment: nope it did not work , just to try whether the .htaccess working or nope, i deleted profile.php?u=$1 and its given me 500 internal error. which mean it works. but the url still the same http://localhost/ifinal/profile.php?u=myname

Comment: @user2660611 You made something wrong. It works for me. You have to define `RewriteBase /ifinal/` and enter `http://localhost/ifinal/profile/myname`. Updated codes

Comment: it works with http://localhost/ifinal/profile/myname but the layout doesn't show as u go to profile.php?u=myname and also it only works when you copy this to the address bar. http://localhost/ifinal/profile/myname but when you click on the href it open it as http://localhost/ifinal/profile.php?u=myname

Comment: Why you dont change your `href` links as `profile/myname` instead of `profile.php?u=myname`?

Comment: yeah it does work after i change that , but now my html layout has gone ! any idea why would that happen ?

Comment: @user2660611 Because of using `profile/myname` like under `profile` folder. Try updated codes. Or use `base href` tag : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: now it has become like this http://i.imgur.com/HDDblHY.png . i don't know why. maybe because i'm including the layout of the profile in the main profile in the main folder?

Comment: man that did it. i really appreciate your help. i really dooo. many thanks.